# Number of independent KVL and KCL

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws, nodal-analysis, equation, mesh-analysis

I know that the number of KTL and KCL is related to the number of nodes \$N\$. For KCL there are \$N-1\$ equations while for the KTL there are \$L-(N-1)=L-N+1\$ equations. However I didn't understand how calculate \$L\$. Is it the number of elements in the circuit ? Is it the number of branches of the circuit ?

Consider the following example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVHyft.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The solution given for this circuit has 2 KTL equations and 1 KCL equation.
For the KCL is straightforward because there are only \$2\$ nodes so \$2-1=1\$ equation. For the KTL \$L-2+1=2 \Rightarrow L = 3\$. Why is that ? Should I consider only the branches entering one node ? That is \$(V1, R3)\$, \$(R2)\$ and \$(R4,R1,V2)\$ ?

Another way to figure out the number of KTL equations is by identifying the number of independent meshes. I can only see 2 meshes in this circuit but for a complex circuit how can get this value ?

Comment: Despite Google translate may try to convince, tension =/= voltage :D. It's Kirchhoff's **V**oltage Law, so, KVL.

Comment: Thanks. I will remember that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Huisman explained on his answer, in KCL we have (**N-1**) **independent** equations and for KVL (**L-N+1**) **independent** equations. 
But in the comments you said:

> If L is the number of elements in the circuit then 6−2+1=5≠2. L must be 3 for this circuit otherwise the equation is not satisfied.

There aren't only two nodes in the circuit. The definition, as explained [here](http://www2.siit.tu.ac.th/prapun/ecs203_2014_2/ECS203%202014%20ch%202%20u4.pdf) pg. 6-7, is:

1. Branch: Represents a single circuit element.
2. Node: Junction point between two or more branchs.
3. Mesh/Loop: Closed path without repeating any nodes.

With that, we get a total of 5 nodes. You can check in the same link above the **Fundamental Theorem of Network Topology** to see if the values of branches, nodes and meshes you found are correct. (Yeah, this question is related to graph theory...)

Notice that in KCL you're gonna set one of the nodes as reference, that is why in this method you can find (N-1) independent equations.

__

> Another way to figure out the number of KTL equations is by identifying the number of independent meshes. I can only see 2 meshes in this circuit but for a complex circuit how can get this value ?

If a mesh has a branch that belongs **exclusively** to her, then she is an independent mesh. In a planar circuit, you can always get (**x = number of independent meshes**) equations to solve.

__

> Should I consider only the branches entering one node ? That is (V1,R3), (R2) and (R4,R1,V2) ?

That's one way to simplify the calculations, depending on the circuit. For the given circuit, you can reduce it to one nodal equation and find the voltage at the node shared by R2, R3 and R4. With this variable, you can find all the other parameters.

Comment: Mmm, the linked pdf also says about nodes: *It is **usually** indicated by a dot in a circuit*. I think that statement is at least confusing (maybe it is even incorrect: I think typically there are more nodes **not** indicated by a dot, because dots are used to show circuit wires split, not to show nodes...) Fun fact: apart from the academic circular resistor networks, the pdf almost leaves out all dots....

Comment: @RaulTancredo I believe that the \$(N-1)\$ comes also from the graph theory. A tree is an acyclic graph with no more than \$n -1 \$ edges. The tree is used to create \$L-(N-1)\$ loops (adding one single node will create a loop) which are the meshes in circuit theory.

Comment: @RaulTancredo No I was not referring to the node potentials method. I just made wrong assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that the number of KTL and KCL is related to the number of nodes \$N\$. For KCL there are \$N-1\$ equations while for the KTL there are \$L-(N-1)=L-N+1\$ equations.

You should add one word:
For KCL there are \$N-1\$ **independent** equations while for the KVL there are \$L-(N-1)=L-N+1\$ **independent** equations.

> However I didn't understand how calculate L. Is it the number of elements in the circuit? Is it the number of branches of the circuit?

Yes, L is the number of elements in the circuit.

> For the KCL is straightforward because there are only \$2\$ nodes [...].

This is incorrect. A node doesn't need to be a black dot...

Comment: With "straightforward" I mean that from a graph point of view there are only 2 nodes with more than 2 edges (which is the definition of circuit node). While for the KVL is not so easy.

Comment: If \$L\$ is the number of elements in the circuit then \$6 - 2+1 = 5 \ne 2\$. \$L\$ must be \$3\$ for this circuit otherwise the equation is not satisfied.

Comment: @Bemipefe Who says that a "circuit node" must have more than 2 edges? Your definition of "node" is not consistent with the definition commonly used in electrical engineering. Perhaps your question is more related to graph theory and belongs in math.se

Comment: @Bemipefe The definition of a node that I used is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_(circuits)). For **that** definition applies that the number of equations is given in my answer above. If you use a different definition, then those equations don't apply... Check also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_analysis

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The term "edge" is not common in circuit theory but the concept is the same. My professor defines a node as a conjunction between 3 or more components. The node with 2 lines are trivial (the current entering the node is equal and opposite to the current leaving the node) and these equations doesn't count for the KCL. This is why I counted 2 nodes and not 5. The mathematical definition of "node" doesn't have a constraint on the number of edges. \$N-1\$ and \$L -(N-1)\$ come from the graph theory (a graph  is created from the circuit then a tree is choose as reference).

Comment: @Huisman With the definition that you provided the total number of KVL (5 nodes ans 6 components) is 6−5+1=2. As I said in the previous comment the definition given by my professor was different and this confused me. Probably that definition can be only used to calculate the total number of independent KCL equations while for the KVL all nodes (including the "2-edges" nodes) must be counted.

Comment: @Bemipefe Yes, I'm thinking how the definition of your professor can be used to derive useful statements about the number of equations

Comment: A dot is used to indicate a conjunction of 3 or more circuit wires. By definition such a dot is a voltage node (with the exception of a short circuit). But as discussed, **there can be more nodes than dots**.

Comment: @Bemipefe If you consider a circuit consisting of 1 voltage source connected to 1 resistor, there are **0** dots/"multiple-edge" nodes, so N = 0. I fail to make a useful statement with using (N-1)…

Comment: @Bemipefe If you consider Figure 2 on the wikipage ["Mesh analysis"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_analysis). In this figure there would be 2 dots. There are 2 meshes/KVL. However, considering Figure 2 on that page, there would be 4 dots, while there only 3 meshes/KCL. So, I fail to relate the number of dots/"multiple-edge" nodes to the number of equations for KCL or KVL. Maybe you should ask a new question if these dots/"multiple-edge" nodes give relevant information solving a circuit.

Comment: @Huisman The only thing I noticed is that usually the professor only write the equations for the KCL related to the "dots" minus the ground node(that is -1). So for example for the circuit above the professor wrote only 1 KCL and 2 KVL. I suppose that the equation like \$I_{R4} + I_{R2} = 0\$ are useless for the equation system and it can be solved also without them.